# Print Report for a desktop winforms application

Tags: c#

I have all the data I need to print in a `SqlDataAdapter` and also in `DataTable`. Now I want to generate and print a report with all the data. Also I would like to add a header to each page containing the company name, address and telephone number.

I am developing using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also Report Viewer set of reporting rools library and even language for reporting. It is free and it it came from Microsoft more info at http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

Comment: I managed to create the report. Thanks for the tutorial. Another problem I am facing is that I want to create a report from an existing data which can then be printed from a dot matrix printer!

Comment: Can this report, which has been generated in tabular form, be printed from a DOP/

Comment: @Saurabh Sorry what is DOP/ and for Dot Matrix printing I think that if you want to use Fast Printing then you need to crate your report from code there is tutorial google it ,also  You can print that as any other Image, or pdf but I think that DotMatrix is not going to be fast as it should be

Comment: That is what i am not able to do. Sorry for the trouble, but i am not able to understand the code for printing. Hence i am not able to format the report as I would like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Options include creating a pdf using a library such as ITextSharp or PDFSharp.

Also, there are some free reporting options out there such as:

neoReports (on CodeProject.com).

I've used Crystal Reports for .NET, but its a real pain to use.

EDIT: In light of the additional Dot Matrix requirement, I'm thinking you should not use any reporting system.  Instead, just write everything to a text file, then print that.  You can mess around with the formatting to make it look how you want.  Keep it simple.

Comment: I dont want to create a pdf...m not sure though but can one print a pdf file from a dot matrix printer? I want to create a report from an existing data which can then be printed from a dot matrix printer!

Comment: @Saurabh -You need to include details like that in your question.  Otherwise we have no idea what your looking for.

Comment: That is what i am not able to do. Sorry for the trouble, but i am not able to understand the code for printing. Hence i am not able to format the report as I would like it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [DevExpress Xtra Reports](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Crystal Report` available in visual studio.
[Crystal Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287920%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for Visual Studio .NET is the standard reporting tool for Visual Studio .NET; it brings the ability to create interactive, presentation-quality content — which has been the strength of Crystal Reports for years — to the .NET platform.

Comment: @Thomas: the problem with crystal reports is that they are not included with the visual studio 2010 edition.

Comment: @user759911: are you working on a Windows application or WebApplication?

Comment: @Thomas: Windows application. Also i want to make sure that the report I create can be printed from a Dot Matrix printer.

Comment: @user759911:you can use this [CRYSTAL REPORTS FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2010](http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp)